# Reporting Services Folder Configuration

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

As a Newbie for Reporting Services, I have some confusion about setting up report services on my local dev machine.  I'm using Sql-Server 2008 Developer Edition on Vista64 Home Premium.

When I go to http://localhost/reports, I'm being asked for a login.  When I enter an account that I have configured to be a local admin, I get to minimal report server screen that does not give me the option to configure the folder structure.

Can I get some advice on how to configure system so that I can get to this step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much experimentation, I finally did a search with "vista insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied) 2008" trying to figure out why I could not see the report server info.

I found http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/e8da121a-c0ac-4d0b-8774-abd5128d88fe which gives the answer.  Many thanks to "rmcphaul" for his answer that I am copying below -

> Here is the final solution.  Hopefully
>   this will help some people who try to
>   get Reporting Services for SQL 2008
>   Developer working on Windows Vista
>   using IE8.  To restate, I was having
>   two issues.  One was that I was being
>   prompted to log in everytime I went to
>   http://[computername]/reports.  The
>   other was that once there I was only
>   seeing the reporting services header. 
>   Everything I was experiencing was
>   related to Vista User Access Control
>   (UAC).  Here are the steps to get it
>   working WITH UAC ON.  Maybe someone
>   can post this to their blog since
>   everything out there seems to relate
>   to SSRS 2005 and/or IE7.
>
> Environment
>
> ·          Vista Ultimate 64 Bit
>
> ·          Internet Explorer 8
>
> ·          SQL Server 2008 Developer
>   with Reporting Services installed
>
> ·          UAC is on.
>
> Issue
>
> When you browse to
>   http://[ComputerName]/Reports it
>   prompts you to login
>
> Cause
>
> This is caused by UAC.  Even if you
>   run Internet Explorer as
>   Administrator, once you log in you are
>   no longer running with administrative
>   privileges.
>
> Resolution 1
>
> 1. Open Internet Explorer
> 2. Click on the "Tools" menu and select "Internet Options"
> 3. Click on the "Security" tab
> 4. Click once on "Local intranet"
> 5. Click on the "Sites" button
> 6. Click on the "Advanced" button
> 7. Make sure "Require server verification (https:) for all sites in
>      this zone is unchecked.
> 8. Add "http://[ ComputerName]" to the Websites list.
> 9. Click the "Close" button to close the Advanced window.
> 10. Click the “Custom Level” button near the bottom.
> 11. Scroll down to the end and you will see the “User Authentication”
>       section.
> 12. User “User Authentication” and then “Logon” verify that “Automatic
>       logon only in Intranet Zone” is
>       selected.  If not select it.
> 13. Click “OK” to close the Security Settings - Local Intranet Zone window.
> 14. Click the "OK" button to close the Local intranet window.
> 15. Click the "OK" button to close the Internet Options Window
> 16. Close Internet Explorer
> 17. Re-open Internet Explorer and browse to http://[
>       ComputerName]/Reports.  You should no
>       longer be prompted to login.
>
> Resolution 2
>
> 1. Open Internet Explorer
> 2. Click on the "Tools" menu and select "Internet Options"
> 3. Click on the "Security" tab
> 4. Click once on "Trusted sites"
> 5. Click on the "Sites" button
> 6. Make sure "Require server verification (https:) for all sites in
>      this zone is unchecked.
> 7. Add "http://[ComputerName]" to the Websites list.
> 8. Click the "Close" button to close the Trusted Sites window.
> 9. You should now be back on the "Security" tab of "Internet Options".
> 10. Make sure "Trusted Sites" is still selected and click the "Custom
>       Level" button near the bottom.
> 11. Scroll down to the end and you will see the "User Authentication"
>       section.
> 12. Under "User Authentication" and then "Logon" select the option that
>       says "Automatic login with current
>       user name and password"/
> 13. Click "OK" to close the Security Settings - Trusted Sites Zone window.
> 14. Click the "OK" button to close the Internet Options Window
> 15. Close Internet Explorer
> 16. Re-open Internet Explorer and browse to
>       http://[ComputerName]/Reports.  You
>       should no longer be prompted to login.
>
> Issue
>
> When you browse to
>   http://[ComputerName]/reports you only
>   see the Report Manager header.
>
> Cause
>
> This is caused by UAC.  By default
>   Reporting Services should allow
>   members of the Local Administrators
>   group access to reporting services but
>   with UAC turned On Reporting Services
>   is not recognizing the logged in user
>   as part of the Local Administrators
>   group.  You will need to explicitly
>   add your account inside reporting
>   services.
>
> Verification
>
> You can verify this issue by browsing
>   to http://[ComputerName]/ReportServer.
>   You should receive a message that
>   says: The permissions granted to user
>   '[UserLogin]' are insufficient for
>   performing this operation.
>   (rsAccessDenied).
>
> Resolution
>
> 1. Open Internet Explorer in Administrator mode by right clicking
>      on the IE icon and selecting "Run as
>      administrator".
> 2. Browse to http://[ComputerName]/Reports
> 3. On the home page click on the "Properties" tab
> 4. Click on "New Role Assignment"
> 5. Add your qualified local login as a Content Manger (for example:
>      [ComputerName][LoginName] or
>      [Domain][LoginName])
> 6. Next in the upper right click on "Site Settings"
> 7. On the left menu select "Security"
> 8. Click on "New Role Assignment"
> 9. Add your qualified local login as a System Administrator (for
>      example: [ComputerName][LoginName] or
>      [Domain][LoginName])
> 10. Close Internet Explorer and open normally
> 11. Browse to http://[ComputerName]/Reports and you
>       should be working properly

Comment: I'm having a similar problem and I found this handy. Just that when I open the Report Manager URL in a browser, I can only see the header with 'Home, My Subscriptions, Help' on the top right corner. I can't see the 'Properties' link or tab any where. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: funny in my Reporting Services installation maybe something is corrupt, because "Properties" tab and "New Role Assignment" never shows up, and I'm still having this problem with permissions.

Comment: Could we supress this Authentication Logon dialog on IE?

Comment: This one really helped me.I was banging my head to get the issue resolved for  almost a week.Thank you