# A fast way to get Reporting Services local site working?

Tags: sql-server-2008, configuration, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reinstall

I was here trying to figure out why my Reports manager is empty, there's no tabs at all.

- I installed SQL Server 2008 complete,
  but didn't not configure Reporting
  Services.
- When installing SQL Server
  2008, this Windows 7 version didn't
  have yet IIS installed, I installed
  it later.
- I don't see where is this
  localhost/Reports physically on my
  Hard Drive, where is the physic
  folder?
- I don't see on IIS where is Report folder, would it exist?

[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_bCvG6V5JTUk/TBkp71wepUI/AAAAAAAAAMM/nW69MqioXjM/iis-without-reportingservices.png](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_bCvG6V5JTUk/TBkp71wepUI/AAAAAAAAAMM/nW69MqioXjM/iis-without-reportingservices.png)

- The [site settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508857/reporting-services-folder-configuration) people
  talk about, I can't find it.
- The "Reporting Services" service is running on automatic at SQL Server Configuration Manager.

[alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/_bCvG6V5JTUk/TBknc9ypz_I/AAAAAAAAAME/NbmudObOFGk/report-manager-empty.jpg](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_bCvG6V5JTUk/TBknc9ypz_I/AAAAAAAAAME/NbmudObOFGk/report-manager-empty.jpg)

How can I get Reporting Services this working without struggling?

(I can't see why is necessary to customize all these user permissions)

Comment: Running IE as Administrator, typing http://junior-pc/ReportServer URL and "Administrator" as logon, appears an empty page: junior-pc/ReportServer - /
---------------
---------------
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.0.2531.0

Comment: Ok, now a few minutes later without touching anything,  on IE the link http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?SelectedTabId=PropertiesTab is working and showing more options on "Report Manager". But how to add my user account to which "group"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it working now.

The main problem is that the current user Junior-PC\Junior was not included in "System Administrator" role http://localhost/Reports.

1. Enable Administrator account in Start->Right click Computer->Manage-> Local users and groups ->Groups-> Administrators
2. Run IE as Administrator, type http://localhost/Reports
3. On the top of "Report Manager" window, click on link "Site Settings"
4. On the next page, on the left hand, click on link "Security"
5. On the same page, on the right side, click on the "New role assignment" button
6. Type the full domain and username (for example Junior-PC\Junior) and check the "System administrator" item, then click Ok.

Now you are able to log on http://localhost/Reports as System administrator.

And then, you can create a new Folder, a new shared Datasource and then your reports within the new folder.

You see, the physic reports folder is present where you have put your new "Folder".
I thought IIS would show up some "Reports" folder since localhost URL is being called.